# Run script when YouTube channel goes live

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I want to run a specific script to check some data of a YouTube stream, like title and description, when a specific channel goes live. I'm very open on how to do this, if there already is a program that can write the YouTube live video id and title to a text file, when the stream starts, for example that would work.

Comment: The Data API [has a push-notification service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications). I have never used it though and I don't know if it notifies you when the Channel goes live.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of YouTube API with shell, or execution programming language while true and sleep for each times you like.